# making discord bot command to store message content (python)

Tags: discord, discord.py

[image]
So this is my first time coding an actual project that isn't a small coding task. I've got a bot that runs and responds to a message if it says "hello". I've read the API documentation up and down and really only have a vague understanding of it and I'm not sure how to implement it.

My question right now is how would I go about creating a command that takes informationn from a message the command is replying to (sender's name, message content) and stores it as an object. Also, what would be the best way to store that information?

I want to learn while doing this and not just have the answers handed to me ofc, but I feel very lost. Not sure where to even begin.

I tried to find tutorials on coding discord bots that would have similar functions to what I want to do, but can't find anything.

Comment: The best way to store that kind of information is in a database. Either way, storing message content is against Discord TOS so you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

#### Intro :

Hi NyssaDuke !

First of all, prefer to paste your code instead of a picture. It's easier for us to take your code and try to produce what you wish.

In second, I see an "issue" in your code since you declare twice the `bot`. You can specify the `intents` when you declare your bot as `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)`

Finally, as stated by @stijndcl , it's against TOS, but I will try to answer you at my best.

#### filesystem

My bot needs to store data, like users ID, language, and contents relative to a game, to get contacted further. Since we can have a quite big load of requests in a small time, I prefered to use a file to store instead of a list that would disappear on crash, and file allow us to make statistics later. So I decided to use `pytables` that you can get via `pip install pytables`. It looks like a small DB in a single file. The file format is HDF5.

Let say we want to create a `table` containing `user name` and `user id` in a file :

```
import tables

class CUsers (tables.IsDescription) : 
    user_name = StringCol(32)
    user_id = IntCol()

with tables.open_file("UsersTable.h5", mode="w") as h5file : 
    groupUser = h5file.create_group("/", "Users", "users entries")
    tableUser = h5file.create_table(groupUser, "Users", CUsers, "users table")
```

We have now a file `UsersTable.h5` that has an internal table located in `root/Users/Users` that is accepting `CUsers` objects, where, therefore, `user_name` and `user_id` are the columns of that table.

#### getting user info and storing it

Let's now code a function that will register user infos, and i'll call it `register`. We will get the required data from the Context that is passed with the command, and we'll store it in file.

```
@bot.command(name='register')
async def FuncRegister (ctx) : 
    with tables.open_file("UsersTable.h5", mode="a") as h5file : 
        tableUser = h5file.root.Users.Users
        particle = tableUser.row
        particle['user_name'] = str(ctx.author)
        particle['user_id'] = ctx.author.id
        particle.append()
        tableUser.flush()
```

The last two lines are sending the `particle`, that is the active `row`, so that is an object `CUsers`, into the file.

An issue I got here is that special characters in a nickname can make the code bug. It's true for "é", "ü", etc, but also cyrillic characters. What I did to counter is to encode the user name into bytes, you can do it by :

```
        particle['user_name'] = str(ctx.author).encode()
```

#### reading file

It is where it starts to be interesting. The HFS5 file allows you to use kind of sql statements. Something you have to take in mind is that strings in the file are UTF-8 encoded, so when you extract them, you have to call for `.decode(utf-8)`. Let's now code a function where a user can remove its entry, based on its id :

```
@bot.command(name="remove")
async def FuncRemove(ctx) : 
    with tables.open_file("UsersTable.h5", mode="a") as h5file : 
        tableUser = h5file.root.Users.Users
        positions = tableUser.get_where_list("(user_id == '%d')" % ctx.author.id)
        nameuser = tableUser[positions[0]]['user_name'].decode('utf-8')
        tableUser.remove_row(positions[0])
```

`.get_where_list()` returns a list of positions in the file, that I later address to find the right position in the table.

#### bot.fetch_user(id)

If possible, prefer saving ID over name, as it complicates the code with encode() and decode(), and that bots have access to a wonderful function that is `fetch_user()`. Let's code a last function that will get you the last entry in your table, and with the id, print the username with the fetch method :

```
@bot.command(name="last")
async def FuncLast(ctx) : 
    with tables.open_file("UsersTable.h5", mode="r") as h5file : 
        tableUser = h5file.root.Users.Users
        lastUserIndex = len(tableUser) - 1
        iduser = tableUser[lastUserIndex]['user_id']
        member = await bot.fetch_user(iduser)
        await ctx.send(member.display_name)
```

For further documentation, check the manual of discord.py, this [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) to `context` in particular.